# It always show either one output, either it highlight the keywords or only the alert box,how to achieve both at the same time

Tags: javascript

```
//grab all div elements in the pages; 
let elt = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var i;
var b = [];

b[0] = "password";
b[1] = "update";
b[2] = "account";
b[3] = "blocked";
b[4] = "alert";
b[5] = "confirm";
b[6] = "cash";
b[7] = "extra";
b[8] = "subscribe";
b[9] = "sample";
b[10] = "winner";
b[11] = "offer";
b[12] = "promotion";
b[13] = "urgent";
b[14] = "action";
b[15] = "update";
b[16] = "luxury";
b[17] = "limited";
b[18] = "login";
b[19] = "alert";
b[20] = "income";
b[21] = "bonus";
b[22] = "verify";
b[23] = "banking";
b[24] = "lowest";
b[25] = "deal";
b[26] = "unusual log in activity";



function scanDOM() {
  //loop for html elements;


  for (i = 0; i < elt.length; i++) {
    var singleDiv = elt[i];
    //loop for keywords;


    for (j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
      var str = singleDiv.innerHTML;
      if (str.indexOf(b[j]) > -1) {


        //if found that the keywords match with the one in array, it will highlight the words;
        str = str.replace(b[j], '<span style="background-color:#f6ff00;">' + b[j] + '</span>');
        singleDiv.innerHTML = str;
        popup();
      }
    }
  }
}


// scan through the pages every 5 seconds;
setInterval(scanDOM, 5000);



//alert message;
function popup() {
  alert * ("**WARNING!**");*
}
```

Comment: for each loop you are showing the alert pop up, please change it outside the loop !

Comment: Thank you! It did help me out. @Vinod kumar